# Solving system of equations with mixed variable types

Tags: diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

I'm looking for solutions to the non-linear system of equations
$$
n_1x + (n_1 - 1)y = a_1 \\
n_2x + (n_2 - 1)y = a_2 \\
n_3x + (n_3 - 1)y = a_3 \\
n_4x + (n_4 - 1)y = a_4
$$
where $x$ and $y$ are positive rational numbers, $(n_i)$ are positive integers and $(a_i)$ are known positive rational constants. Any clues?

Geometrically, this can be interpreted as determining the length $x$ of an object so that when placing $n_i$ instances of the object after one another with a distance of $y$ between each object they will add up to a total length of $a_i$.

Comment: If this is an applied problem then why not just solve with any nonlinear solver (for given $a_i$'s) and then round to integer quantities?

Comment: Maesumi: OK, thanks for the tip. I will try that.